# nodejs how to pass Date from service to Express API

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mean-stack

I have the following code in my service:

```
var currentDate = new Date();


return this._authHttp
  .get(
    `localhost:3000/listJobs?filter={"where": {"expireDate":{"$gte": new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), currentDate.getMonth(), currentDate.getDay())}}}`
  )
  .map((res: Response) => res.json())
  .catch(this.handleError);
```

and my API:

```
module.exports.listJobs = (req, res) => {
   var queryFilter = {};

   let condition = {};
   if (req.query.filter) {
     queryFilter = JSON.parse(req.query.filter);
   }
   if (queryFilter.where) {
     condition = queryFilter.where;
   }



    myCollection.find(condition).exec(function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      sendJsonResponse(res, 400, err);
    } else {
      sendJsonResponse(res, 200, result);
    }
  });
};
```

What i want to do is: have a generic API route to support dynamic query filters, suppose in one another condition i have another function in my service that pass different filters to the same route.
What i want to know is how we can pass `ObjectId(), new Date(), etc...`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, try to send an object with properties for filter in service.
If I understood right you write a client part using Angular 2.
Example:

```
let params: URLSearchParams = objToSearchParams(obj);

 return this.http.get('url', {
   search: params
 }).subscribe(
   (response) => //some manipulation with response 
 );

 function objToSearchParams(obj): URLSearchParams{
    let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key))
            params.set(key, obj[key]);
    }
    return params;
 }
```